# How can I create a simple datapicker in PHP?

Tags: php, datapicker

How can I create a simple datapicker in PHP?

Comment: @Stephen, please be nice to newbies. (I do agree with your general point about 'put some effort in it first' though)

Comment: @Jacco Agreed, sorry, my frustration got the better of me. I removed the comment.

Comment: datapicker or datepicker..... confused... trying to fix the question

Comment: You would be better off using JQuery I would have thought, http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ try this

Answer (score 0):

if datepicker is what you are asking, here are some help full links for it

http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3338-PHP-Generate-form-input-to-pick-a-calendar-date.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpdatepicker/

http://www.scriptdungeon.com/freephpscript/freescripts725